# EPPlus 4.5.2.1 NuGet package corruption

Tags: epplus

From what I can tell, the NuGet package for 4.5.2.1 seems to be corrupt. All previous packages I can download are fine, but the 4.5.2.1 throws errors when queried with nuget.exe as well as any attempted opening with the Package Explorer or using Zip.

Has anyone else seen this issue?

---

[image: 7-Zip Error]

[image: Nuget Package Explorer Error]

Comment: No, can't reproduce. Works fine for me. Do you still have this issue?

Comment: Yes I do - I just re-downloaded and if I attempt to open with WinRar or 7-Zip I get an end of archive. The previous version opens just fine. Also does not open correctly with the package explorer.

Comment: I should add I'm downloading directly from NuGet.org.

Comment: I just went to https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus and clicked "Download  (1.89 MB)" link. Changed extension to zip and extracted with no problem. Perhaps you could add pictures of what you want to do.

Comment: I had same issue with 7-zip and with the Nuget Package Explorer (fresh install) - updated question with images (has to be peer reviewed to be displayed to all)

Comment: Added issue on Github here with images: https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/issues/271

Comment: I have since added images to my original issue post here. https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/issues/254